# Value not updating in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a users table in which i have a column name is_privacy. I have made a service  post "users/:id/privacy", to: 'users#privacy'.I have use postgresql as my database is_privacy is my boolean column and the value it generally saves is TRUE OR FALSE

```
 def privacy
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.is_privacy == TRUE
      @user.is_privacy= FALSE  
    else
      @user.is_privacy = TRUE
    end
    puts "ssss#{@user.is_privacy}"
  end
```

It is not hitting the database means it is not change the value in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `@user.save` after setting the value in your action.